# iOS6 MapKit (MKLocalSearch): How to get Address of a mapItem?

Tags: mapkit, ios6-maps, google-local-search

iOS6  Apple MapKit

So I understand the code in the link below for the most part.
http://phpadvocate.com/blog/2013/01/ios-6-1-simple-example-using-mklocalsearch/

However, how do I get the address for the mapItem?  Seems like the other properties include: placemark, isCurrentLocation, name, phoneNumber, and url.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/MKMapItem_class.pdf

Basically, once the data is fetched, I'd like to display the name of the retail location as the cell.text and the address as cell.detailText.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mapItem.placemark.thoroughfare.copy, // Will return first single line address

mapItem.placemark.locality, // Will return City

mapItem.placemark.administrativeArea //Will return State.

Below are some more:

CLPlacemark   |   Property Meaning

Thoroughfare | Street address.  First line if multiple lines.

subThoroughfare | Street address, second line (e.g., apartment or unit number, box number)

Locality | City

SubLocality | This might contain a neighborhood or landmark name, though it’s often nil

administrativeArea | State, province, territory, or other similar unit

dministrativeArea |  County

postalCode |  ZIP code

Country | Country

countryCode | Two-digit ISO country code

Answer (score 3):

To correct the "correct answer", the subThoroughfare doesn't contain apartment number or unit number, it is the house number.

Apartment number is in subPremise, which I do not know how to retrieve yet.